# virtualenv activate script missing

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, python-venv

I have installed python and virtual environment on linux, but every time I try to create a new virtual environment the bin folder is missing many files such as the activate script. I only succeed if I run the follow command:

```
sudo virtualenv myvenv
```

If I only run `virtualenv myvenv` the bin folder is incomplete.

I have also managed to create a virtual enviroment with `python -m venv myvenv`

Why is this happening I dont want to use python3, just python. Any ideas?

Comment: You could run `which virtualenv` to check that the right program is being run.

Comment: @khelwood it gives `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

and 

`virtualenv --version
15.1.0`

Comment: What gives `python --version` (out of your env)

Comment: @Arount `Python 3.5.3`

Comment: it turns out that it only happens when I use python2.7 when I create the virtual environment using `python3 -m venv <myenv>` everything is fine.

Comment: i also suffer this issue.  venv also fails to place an `activate` script into bin.  i'm at a loss!  im unsing virtualenv 15.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , the *Scripts* folder was empty.

I was trying `python -m virtualenv see`

and I was getting an error like :

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\anaconda3\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe
```

I changed replaced virtualenv with venv and it worked.

i.e `python -m venv see`